# Should I use the sqlite_master or does it come with any dangers?

Tags: sqlite

So I am doing a private project including a localized database. Since I am not able to host an SQL Server I decided to implement a system for users to syncronize their data (maybe bluetooth, maybe www, not certain yet).

Now in order to send entire sqlite tables between people and for different visualisations I found it useful to get the column names from tables and interact with them, send data refering to them and so on.

Ive seen posts that conclude to use the sqlite_master table to recieve the data Im interested in, Ive tried, it worked, wonderful. Now I got suspicious.

I read about this master property that it could crash the whole databank in horrible ways, make it unreadable and whatsoever. Other than that there might also be some privacy problems or admin privileges that I may lay open for anyone once I send it incripted or not incripted (thats my private concern, I just read master and think of a system jesus XD).

And I research more and more and I cant find a satisfying answer. Evryone describes how to use the sqlite_master but not why or what dangers come with it (Or maybe Im just blind and didnt see the right post :D)

Well thats my question. Should I use it? Is it recommended to leave it alone? Becouse I could, there are other ways to just save up the tables and their columns in a bunch of strings lying arround somewhere. Id like to use it, becouse its handy, I like working with it more than I like working with PRAGMA. Or shall I really just ignore sqlite_master and move on to different methods?